# Binary Packages for ROS Hydro on ARMHF

Tags: ros, pandaboard, binaries, armhf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have ROS Hydro running on Ubuntu 12.04 (for armhf) on a Pandaboard ES.  I'm having trouble running some of my nodes on this board because packages are missing.  I have tried to install these packages individually using apt-get but I get an "unable to locate package" error.

Are the following binary packages available for armhf?  How can I see what is available and what isn't?

```
moveit_commander
rviz
robot_model
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135246/binary-packages-for-ros-hydro-on-armhf/) by [daalt](https://answers.ros.org/users/9331/daalt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2014-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ARM buildfarm status for Hydro is at: http://packages.namniart.com/repos/status/hydro.html

I haven't tried to build moveit on ARM. If it builds from source easily, I can add it to the build farm and see how it does.

rviz doesn't build on ARM. The OpenGL support and the support libraries aren't there, and I wouldn't expect it to be fast enough even if I could get it to build. The error I'm seeing on the farm is:

```
-- checking for module 'OGRE'
--   found OGRE, version 1.7.4
-- OGRE_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/OGRE-1.7.4
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:91 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find OpenGL (missing: OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:252 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake:153 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:31 (find_package)
```

robot_model isn't building on ARM because it depends on collada_urdf, which fails to build with the following error:

```
lboost_date_time-mt -lboost_system-mt -lboost_thread-mt -lpthread /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libcpp_common.so /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libconsole_bridge.so -lcollada-dom2.4-dp -lboost_program_options-mt -lassimp -Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/hydro/lib:/tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-collada-urdf-1.10.18-1precise-20140221-2137/obj-arm-linux-gnueabihf/devel/lib: 
devel/lib/libcollada_urdf.so: undefined reference to `vtable for Assimp::IOSystem'
devel/lib/libcollada_urdf.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for Assimp::IOSystem'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [devel/lib/collada_urdf/urdf_to_collada] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-collada-urdf-1.10.18-1precise-20140221-2137/obj-arm-linux-gnueabihf'
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/urdf_to_collada.dir/all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-collada-urdf-1.10.18-1precise-20140221-2137/obj-arm-linux-gnueabihf'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-collada-urdf-1.10.18-1precise-20140221-2137/obj-arm-linux-gnueabihf'
dh_auto_build: make -j1 returned exit code 2
make[1]: *** [override_dh_auto_build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-collada-urdf-1.10.18-1precise-20140221-2137'
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [daalt](https://answers.ros.org/users/9331/daalt/) on 2014-03-05**:
Thanks for the excellent response!  Looks like I need to find an Intel-based board for my application.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-05**:
MoveIt and collada_urdf are potentially fixable. If you can verify that they work and/or provide patch files, I can incorporate them into the build process for the ARM build farm.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-05**:
This question suggests that rviz can be built on ARM, but I haven't tested it myself or gotten feedback that it runs well enough to be useful: http://answers.ros.org/question/52098/unable-to-compile-rviz-on-ubuntu-armhf/